# Is IOU an abbreviation, an acronym, or an initialism?

Tags: orthography, abbreviations, acronyms, initialisms, clipping

IOU stands for *I owe you* and we pronounce each letter separately. But how do we classify that construction"?

- **abbreviation**: *a shortened form of a word or phrase*
- **acronym**: *an abbreviation formed from the initial letters of other words and pronounced as a word*
- **Initialism**: *an abbreviation consisting of initial letters pronounced separately*
- **back-formation**: *a word that is formed from an existing word which looks as though it is a derivative, typically by removal of a suffix*

<sup>All definitions provided by Oxford Dictionaries Online</sup>

It can't be an abbreviation because there is no shortening, clipping or back-formation. Take for example *phone* which is an abbreviation of *telephone*, or *edit* which is a back-formation of *editorship* and *editor*. I would argue that abbreviations are words that have been shortened, a faster way of writing or saying something. Another example would be *Prof* for professor.

It can't be an acronym because we don't pronounce IOU as one word, whereas we do with NATO and RAM.

It can't be an initialism because if it was, it should be written as IOY (I Owe You)

Other examples that spring to mind is CU for *see you* and YRU for *why are you*, where initialism would dictate that the proper forms be SY and WAY.

How do linguists define this structure? Is there a more specific term than abbreviation?

Comment: I think you might want to use a broader definition of abbreviation. Wikipedia defines it as a shortening by any method. This could include phonetic.

Comment: great question ... you know, it's like an EARLY ("pre phone!")VERSION of "text spelling".  Which is quite amazing.

Comment: you know, it's rather like "OK" in a way.  in a category of its own.

Comment: @JoeBlow  OK standing for okay or all correct (whatever) etc. I'm also tempted to think it is a separate category. Be nice to have an "official" answer, if poss.

Comment: ("okay" was only backformed from "OK" I believe - as you know the origin of OK {which, apparently, is the **single most understood word in all languages on the entire planet -- how cool is that?**} are shrouded in mystery; but (like IOU) it's simply "not" a real abbreviation, it's kind of a whacky "text-message-spelling" thing.  Anyways - I don't know :)

Comment: And IOU is much older than text messaging.

Comment: I think the issue here is more on phonetics rather than writing!

Comment: I'd say that technically it's a phonetic initialism.  Not that it slapping a label on it makes one whit of difference to the world.

Comment: @JoeBlow - Obviously, "OK" is a shortened form of "okey-dokey". ;)

Comment: An onomatopoeia?

Comment: Just wait till you get to  QT for *cutey*, EZ for *easy*, or B̄Q̄
 for *barbecue*: trust me, it’s all downhill from there.:)  Especially once you include digits, so B4 for *before*, B9 for *benign*, 1K for *wonky*, W8 for *wait*, and much **much** worse, like somebody getting IR8 cause their partner was 2S9 & 4GO2 say 10Q after 4N6, losing out on a chance 2 4NK8 L8R. :) That’s Y 4N XL8Rs ❤ EZ words — & H8 2C ÞE words 2XL8 like μC4S.

Comment: @tchrist "Okay, I know what that means...yeah, I've heard that...wait, hold on, that seems a little forced...but—but—...I don't... _what_ ..." [head explodes]

Comment: @tchrist - Anyone who knows anything knows that barbecue is abbreviated "BBQ".

Comment: @tchrist "like someone getting irate cause their partner was tosnine (?!) and forgot to say thank you after phone sex, losing out on a chance to fornicate later..." and I'm too tired to work out the rest...

Comment: @Mari-LouA *Too asinine*.

Comment: @tchrist nice 1

Comment: @tchrist: "That's why foreign translators love easy words—and hate to see the(?) words to translate like (mucus?)" (Why is _xl8_ "translate"?)

Comment: @JustinGreer Hate to see thorny words like *muciferous*.

Comment: Reminds me of how long it took me to figure out the cleverness behind the chat program named ICQ.

Comment: I was about to add an elipsis to the title until I realised you posted it M-L; this allows the spot-on neologism answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It could be characterized as a *[rebus](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rebus)*

> a riddle or puzzle made up of letters, pictures, or symbols whose names sound like the parts or syllables of a word or phrase [*Merriam-Webster*]

While a rebus often contains images, letters being used to represent syllables is common.

[image: rebus card]

[*[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus)*]

In particular, the [Encyclopaedia Britannica](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/493346/rebus) states

> Literary rebuses use letters, numbers, musical notes, or specially placed words to make sentences. Complex rebuses combine pictures and letters. Rebuses may convey direct meanings, especially to inform or instruct illiterate people; or they may deliberately conceal meanings, to inform only the initiated or to puzzle and amuse.
>
> ....
>
> A familiar English rebus is the debtor’s “IOU,” for “I owe you.”

If you wanted to be more precise in defining it, you could say *alphabetic rebus*.

Comment: Interesting idea, but aren't rebuses supposed to be solved? IOU doesn't need to be deciphered.

Comment: Actually, for those unfamilar with the term (those who arrive in a space ship, or time travellers from the past, or maybe new English speakers) it *does* have to be puzzled out. You can't pronounce it phonetically. You kind of have to read it aloud, like an initialism, to get it.

Comment: Not my downvote! I think the concept is novel (to me in any case). Could you find anything else about it? Linguistically speaking is it a used term?

Comment: "Literary rebuses use **letters**, numbers, musical notes, or specially placed words to make sentences."

Comment: Ian Rankin includes a very good example of such a thing in one of his Inspector Rebus novels.  " (can't remember the first line).. A Q I C I 8 2 Q B 4 I P"   Never knew that rebus was the word for them though.

Comment: I think you should add that quote I posted, tchrist's usage of letters and numbers e.g. "*4GO2 say*" really do make my head spin, they are, for all intents and purposes riddles/puzzles.

Comment: @Mari-LouA *Non verbis sed rebus* shall ye know them. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA With a lot of the recent rebuses in chat-speak, anyone not familiar with the solutions will have to look them up or infer them from the letters and / or context.  IOU is a very common puzzle, where the solution is widely distributed; however, it is still something that has "the need to decipher", from my dealings with English as a second language speakers and first grade children.  The core set of English rules provide nothing to the meaning without some additional puzzle solving via phonetic association.

Answer (score 16):

I think it is a *phonetic [abbreviation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/abbreviation)* in the sense that IOU represents the (phonetics) sound of “I Owe You”, not its proper initials, similar to CU for “see you”.    (From The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language)

> - The act or product of shortening.
> - A shortened form of a word or phrase used chiefly in writing to represent the complete form, such as Mass. for Massachusetts or *USMC for United States Marine Corps.*

[IOU](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/iou.asp): (from Investopedia)

> - An informal document that acknowledges a debt owed. *IOU is an abbreviation*, in phonetic terms, of "I owe you".

Comment: I think abbreviation can cover everything. I'm curious if there is a more *specific* term.

Comment: I see your point..but in your question you say' It can't be an abbreviation'.

Comment: @medica I think it's closer to an initialism, each letter represents a word. But, until a few years ago I had never heard of clipping or back-formation, so maybe there's a term out there. I tend to think of abbreviations more like shortenings, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You're right.

Comment: You know, I'm not convinced that "abbreviation" covers everything. If you asked your Mom what an abbreviation is, she'd probably think you mean "it uses initials".  Almost anyone, I reckon, would say IOU is a "weird" abbreviation; indeed coz it is not initials-based.

Comment: *phonetic abbreviation* ohh, tempting. Needs something more official, or an explanation as to why you think this is so.

Comment: well, the explanation is that IOU represent the  (phonetics) sound of I Owe You, not the proper initials. Same as CU for 'see you'.

Comment: "in phonetic terms" is mentioned in your source...

Comment: Yes..I think phonetics are a key to this issue. That why I chose that source.

Comment: I would upvote you twice if I could. I think this is the answer.

Comment: Another slang version of this type of phonetic that I've heard recently is UOENO which is meant to mean "you don't even know". Very interesting from a grammatical standpoint.

Comment: I think the **phonetics** would be /aɪoʊju/ or /ajowju/ depending on your transcription ideas about inter-vocalic glides.

Comment: The specific term is acronym.

Answer (score 4):

It is a gramogram or grammagram.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramogram#Examples_of_sentences

> A gramogram or grammagram or letteral word is a letter or group of letters which can be pronounced to form one or more words, as in "CU" for "See you". They are a subset of rebuses, and are commonly used as abbreviations.

Comment: I was asking myself how it was possible that no one posted this as an answer when I looked at the history of the Wikipedia article, and realised it was [first created in 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gramogram&oldid=757610042). Two years *after* I had originally posted my question.

Answer (score 3):

[*Initialism*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/initialism): an abbreviation consisting of the first letter or letters of words in a phrase, **syllables or components of a word**, or **a combination of words and syllables** and pronounced by spelling out the letters one by one rather than as a solid word. - AHDEL

There is also [*alphabetism*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/alphabetism) (Farlex Trivia Dictionary): The expression of spoken sounds by an alphabet; the **representation of the sounds of speech in consistent graphic form.**

> Initialisms (sometimes called alphabetisms) are formed from the initial letters of a string of words and are pronounced as a sequence of letters, e.g. BYOB, USA, DVD. Acronyms are formed from the initial letters or parts of words in a sequence, but have the distinction of being pronounceable words, e.g. RADAR, SCUBA.

[*Glottopedia*](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Alphabetism) defines alphabetisms as follows: an abbreviation that takes the first letter of each word of the base expression (like an acronym), and is pronounced by spelling out each letter.

But [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alphabetism) defines it as the use of letters as symbols; the representation of speech sounds by vowel and consonantal rather than syllabic signs. (IOU seems to fit that bill.)

[Mindmap](http://www.mindomo.com/mindmap/abbreviation-vs-acronyms-ae6fdce28c434804b2c97135537cc72d) has subctegories of acronyms which are interesting to consider, including *bacronym*: refers to a word which seems like an acronym, but actually isn't, and states the difference between an acronym and an initialism is that an acronym forms a new word, while an initalism does not; you say "U.K." is an intialism for United Kindom: *the periods are a dead-giveaway that's it's an intialism* (but it's not an authoritative source).

Wikipedia, citing Homeland Security, calls it a pseudo-acronym, but the cited article doesn't list IOU.

I think it's a homoiousia of an alphabetism.

Comment: FYI is "for your information" and I have begun hearing people actually saying "eff wai/wye i"  but said aloud neither -Y nor -F replace their corresponding word. On the contrary, -Y sounds like the word "why". Interestingly if you look up FYI many dictionaries list it as an abbreviation, and not an initialism. Which kinda bring us back to square one :))

Comment: @Mari-LouA - indeed it does, and my head is spinning. See edit.

Comment: I now want a t-shirt with "I think it's a homoiousia of an alphabetism." on it.

Comment: Hey, did you just say something despective about analphabetics? :)